# Filter function in Google Sheet - multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a table with names of performers and the activities they performed in which cities. Now, I am trying to find out who all performed in which city using filter formula - Check C15 in below sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19U0vjtABXQ-MltxZoW7v0vjt1L6gM2Lc2VP3Z-BuKwE/edit?usp=sharing

The formula I am trying to use is:

```
=join(", ",transpose(iferror(filter(A2:A11,REGEXMATCH(C2:G11,"Chicago")))))
```

If I change G11 to C11 in above formula, I can see some output which is incorrect.

- (a) I want the names of performers who performed in Chicago from columns C all the way to G.
- (b) Even if I keep it as C11, it gives the name of only the first performer.. and not all those who performed in Chicago in column C

For just Chicago, the output should be:

> Nils, Tom in **F15**
>   Nils, Tom, Jack, Amanda, Sam in **C15**

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=join(", ",transpose(iferror(filter(A2:A11,REGEXMATCH(B2:B11,"Chicago")))))
```

works for me and I get Nils,Tom in F15.

One way of getting the matches in all columns is to get the row totals like this, and where they aren't zero to join the values in the first column:

```
=ArrayFormula(textjoin(",",true,if(mmult(n(regexmatch(B$2:G$11,A15)),transpose(column(B:G))),A$2:A$11,)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
=join(", ",transpose(filter(A2:A11,REGEXMATCH(C2:C11&D2:D11&E2:E11&F2:F11&G2:G11,"Chicago"))))
```

Comment: Thanks Rory for helping out. Technically this should work well too. However, have used Tom's solution above.